# Is there any use for an allocated but un-accessible SSD-drive?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I recently got a new Lenovo Y510P Laptop, with a 24 GB SSD drive and a 1 TB Hard Drive.

When I opened up Disk manager, I realized that the SSD drive was allocated into a single partition, but the partition did not have a drive letter or any visible way to use the memory space.

I cannot think of any reason to have the disk set up this way, and am wondering why it is the default setting.

I also have a question about the default partitioning of the 1 TB Hard Drive [here](https://superuser.com/questions/719216/why-would-there-be-two-separate-recovery-partitions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the size, it may be set up as a cache using something like intel [smart response techology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Response_Technology). This gives you some of the benefits of a SSD, at lower cost without compromising on storage size. Anandtech has a very [in depth writeup](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4329/intel-z68-chipset-smart-kjbbjhresponse-technology-ssd-caching-review/2) on what SRT is, and you can check if thats the case through the SRT driver - as you can see on the [intel user guide](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-032826.htm)

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it. The SSD in these models is used as a cache.

Comment: Although I don't have the same UI for Intel rapid stora.... It appears to be the same.