# Why would there be two separate recovery partitions

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

I recently got a new Lenovo Y510P Laptop, with Windows 8.1, a 24 GB SSD drive, and a 1 TB Hard Drive.

When I opened up Disk manager, I realized that the Hard Drive was partitioned into six segments:

- Two primary accessible partitions each with their own drive letter (one has OS)
- one 260 MB EFI System partition (Boot partition)
- one 1000 MB OEM partition (probably lenovo software)
- one 1000 MB recovery partition
- one 12.52 GB recovery partition

I am wondering why there are two recovery partitions and what possible use they could have because one seems to be too small to fit anything.

Comment: Very similar to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/666020/windows-8-1-why-are-there-multiple-recovery-partitions-in-the-system) question, but it doesn't have any answers.

Comment: Without looking at what's inside either of them, one might be the recovery environment and the other will have the recovery image on it.

Comment: @MichaelFrank What would the recovery environment be used for?  Is there any advantage to having them separate?  Also, both recovery partitions are completely unused.

Comment: I don't pretend to know exactly why they're like that. The Recovery Environment needs to be able to boot separately from Windows. As for why the partitions are empty, I would hazard a guess that either Windows just can't view the partitions correctly, or they don't have anything yet as you haven't created any recovery media yet. Lenovo have a very good support team, you'd probably find out if you called them.

Answer (score 1):

See Lenovo's article titled [Understanding hard drive partitions on Lenovo systems with Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows 8 - ThinkCentre, ThinkStation, ThinkPad](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht077144):

> For Microsoft Windows 8, which requires three partitions, Lenovo
>   created the Recovery Partition to allow the recovery of the initial
>   operating system and software on the computer to the same state that
>   they were in before the computer was activated. ... The far left small
>   Recovery Partition, EFI System Partition and Windows 8 operating
>   system partition, is required by Windows 8.  The larger Recovery
>   Partition is the Lenovo created partition.

There's also an explanation of Lenovo's partitioning scheme in a response to [New G580 has seven partitions, Help identify?](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/New-G580-has-seven-partitions-Help-identify/m-p/1154103#M44848) on the Lenovo support forum:

> 1. WINRE_DRV 1000MB OEM - this is the [Windows Recovery Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Recovery_Environment#Windows_Recovery_Environment) - this has it's own interface / it doesn't need the 7th partition to operate
> 2. SYSTEM_DRV 260MB System - [check this thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/SYSTEM-DRV-partition-what-is-it-what-does-it-do/td-p/491653)
> 3. LRS_ESP 1000MB OEM- The third partition is the [EFI System partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_Partition) which is used for data storage for the Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) interface
> 4. (blank) 128MB MSR - The fourth partition is the [Microsoft Reserved Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) which is also used for data storage for the Globally Unique Identifier (GUID).
> 5. Windows8_OS 884.2GB Primary - Windows 8 OS
> 6. LENOVO 25GB Primary - this contains the Application and Drivers that are preloaded on the OS (the drivers listed on this folder are also available on the lenovo website)
> 7. PBR_DRV 20GB OEM - this is your recovery partition - you will need to press the [One Key Recovery](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=HT062552) button to activate this partition.